# Short story about a woman living in a plague/natural disaster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story I read in middle school (so probably around 2007 to 2008).

It is about a young woman who has recently moved somewhere warm, I believe it was Florida. However, some kind of natural disaster or other apocalyptic event has turned the sky dark and it's very cold. She mentions being ill-equipped for the new environment since she anticipated living in sunny Florida.

There isn't a lot of food and she has to fight people at the grocery store for scraps. After some time, I (think?) soldiers come and tell her they are relocating her to somewhere safe. She believes she sees a blue sky but in fact this is some kind of hallucination because the soldiers actually shot her. It was pretty grim for a story being presented to middle schoolers.

I have to tried to search for "short story woman florida apocalypse" and other search terms, but I can't find it.

Comment: What is the "plague" part of this?

Comment: You read it in 2008, but do you know when it would have been published?

Comment: My memory is hazy but the closest event I could think of is probably a nuclear winter. Permanently gray skies, always cold, little food, etc. Not sure about publish date, I'm sorry. I know I read it online, if that helps.